# Installing ruby on ubuntu on my first VPS

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv

I'm new to ruby and ubuntu and just created my first VPS droplet for deployment of my rails app. For setting it up I followed Railscast [#335](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps), which recommended using `rbenv-installer` for installing Ruby.

After [running](https://github.com/fesplugas/rbenv-installer):

```
 curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fesplugas/rbenv-installer/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash
```

I get the message:

```
Seems you still have not added 'rbenv' to the load path:

# ~/.bash_profile:

export RBENV_ROOT="${HOME}/.rbenv"

if [ -d "${RBENV_ROOT}" ]; then
  export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

The railscast suggests adding it to `~/.bashrc` using `vim` (who ever created this user interface??) and then excuting this file using `. ~/.bashrc` which I followed.

However, when running `rbenv bootsrap-ubuntu-14-4` I get the message:

`The program 'rbenv' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install rbenv`

Which I think is not the point.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Which account do you login to the OS? root or non root?

Comment: I connected using root and then changed to my new 'deployer' account

Comment: It might be easier to use a ppa for a global install if you're only using the VPS for your own apps.  https://www.brightbox.com/blog/2016/01/06/ruby-2-3-ubuntu-packages/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me, thanks to the tip from @kristianp:

https://www.brightbox.com/blog/2016/01/06/ruby-2-3-ubuntu-packages/

`$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng`

`$ sudo apt-get update`

Install the package:

`$ sudo apt-get install ruby2.3 ruby2.3-dev`

And you’re up and running:

$ `ruby2.3 -v`

`ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`

Cheerio!